# google recaptcha V2 on apache shared server: How to get it to work with SSL

Tags: ssl

I implemented google's reCAPTCHA V2 on non-https apache shared server and it worked 100%. I then changed the protocol to my shared server with SSL using the same script as the non-SSL script. The older version of reCaptcha had an SSL 'false' to 'true' SSL parameter, whereas I can't find one for V2.

I had to use htaccess to redirect the example.com to the shared SSL server `https://serverid.net/example/` which works perfectly without recCAPTCHA. I incorporated reCAPTCHA V2 and the error message where the reCAPTCHA image should be shows `ERROR: Invalid domain for site key`.

Here's the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://servername.net/example/$1 [R,L]`
```

[Here's](https://github.com/google/ReCAPTCHA/blob/master/php/recaptchalib.php) the recaptchalib.php code on github in case that helps:

Anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: This is more of an Apache config question.

Comment: This is more of an SO-question because it is about implementing reCAPTCHA on website. Anyway, check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

> The older version of reCaptcha had an SSL 'false' to 'true' SSL parameter, whereas I can't find one for V2.

The API was changed in v2. It should working seamlessly in SSL and non-SSL website.

> The error message where the reCAPTCHA image should be shows ERROR: Invalid domain for site key.

You register your key under example.com. So google reCAPTCHA server expects that user load it from domain `http://example.com`. Now you display it in `http://serverid.net/` which is different with `http://example.com` thus rendering the error message.

> Anyone know how to make this work?

Add your new domain in existing API key. See [this page](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list) for get the reCAPTCHA dashboard

Answer (score 0):

At key settings on the recaptcha page add the domain to the list like:

exampleshared.com

examplehttps.com

Comment: This does not make sense.

Comment: Well, you go to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list and add the domain to the other domain

Comment: This answer is still undecipherable. "Add the thing to the other thing"? What domain? Can you use the OP's data to help provide relevance and context to what you are trying to say?

Comment: For the domain that he has http on (where it worked on) add "https://serverid.net" to the domain list on the recaptcha admin panel

Comment: I tried that, however that is the domain name for all shared users using SSL. The addition of /example.com/ directs to my site in particular.

Comment: You don't need to add the sub directory to the list. just a full TLD should work (the same that the user loads when visiting your page.)